# Dump only 10% of the data in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

While taking a dump, is it possible to specify that we need 10% of the the data(or a fixed amount of records from each table)? The problem is I have a database with large amounts of data and the dump becomes very large. I want to dump so that the dump file will be smaller(not all data is needed).

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to limit the amount of data using a WHERE clause?  If so, the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility offers a `--where` option.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 5

0 -> the starting point
5 -> count of records.

Comment: you mean I have to do this for every table